# sum by groups in matrix in R

Tags: r

so I am starting to learn R and don't know if there is an easy way to sum every n parameters of a matrix going by each row and when it finishes the range move to the other set of columns until all the columns have been computed

```
[1    4    7]
[2    5    8]
[3    6    9]
```

so in this case if n=2 the output should be

```
[5    11    8]
[7    13   10]
[9    15   12]
```

Is there an efficient way? Thank you!

Comment: yes, so if n=2 it will select [1  4] and sum them then [3  9] until finishing

Comment: functions needed to solve this: `apply`, `zoo::rollsum`. Good luck :-)

Comment: Thank you for the patience :)

Answer (score -1):

data:

```
m <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3)
```

setting:

```
n = 2
```

code:

```
t(
apply(m, 1, function(x) { zoo::rollsum(c(x,x), n, align = "left")[seq_along(x)] })
)
```

result:

```
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    5   11    8
#[2,]    7   13   10
#[3,]    9   15   12
```

your homework: :-)

- Next question will be a clear one.
- Reading about every function I have used: for eg type `?t`, `?apply` ... etc into R-console.